# ASP.net Web API- token expire before period setting time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

When i setting expire time 14 days like bellow

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions 
 {
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
 };
 app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
 app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

It works fine in localhost, but when I deploy to web server, token expire after 15 or 20 minutes.

Do I missing setting somewhere ?

Comment: May be our server is share server, if no one active on this, it will auto shutdown app pool after 10 or 15 minutes, and it will make the token invalid. just my guest. thank all